# JNI native call *prototypes* in their own class/namespace?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have written JNI wrappers to export the API of a C application (G-WAN) which embeds a JVM. The native calls are *implemented* in the C application and exported with RegisterNatives().

Ideally I would have a 'gwan' class for the G-WAN API:

```
import gwan // G-WAN API

public class hello {
   public static int jmain(long env, String[] args) {
      gwan.xbuf_cat(gwan.get_reply(env), "Hello World");
      return 200; // HTTP status (200:'OK')
   }
}
```

I would like to do something like the "#import gwan" above to import the native call *prototypes*, but currently I only have the following (which works):

```
public class hello {
   public static int jmain(long env, String[] args) {
      gwan_xbuf_cat(gwan_get_reply(env), "Hello World");
      return 200; // HTTP status (200:'OK')
   }
   public static native long gwan_get_reply(long env);
   public static native void gwan_xbuf_cat(long ctx, String str);
}
```

Again, the *implementation* of the native calls in made in the G-WAN executable (not in a Java class stored on disk).

Because [the G-WAN API is quite large](http://gwan.ch/api/), I would like to have the native call prototypes in their own 'gwan' class (or namespace) if possible (like in the first hello example above).

Any suggestion about how to do that?
(please post Java or JNI code because I am not a Java expert)

Disclamer: I am involved in the development of this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a C programmer, I have had to read the C source code of the JVM to find that Java remaps Class (path) names with dots instead of slashes.

Since the G-WAN directory hierarchy uses IP addresses to define listeners and virtual hosts (`192.168.10.10_80/#domain.com/csp`), those dots were confusing the `FindClass()` JNI call, making it fail to find the classes.

I also found that the classpath path separator is a ":" for Unix and a ";" for Windows. That was not the cause of my problem, but it might cause the same issue.

Finally, I stopped using the GCJ compiler's JVM because it does not support formating `doubles` (since at least 2006). Using either OpenJDK or the SUN/ORACLE JVM works as expected.

All works fine now. I post all this here just in case it may help others.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you read following paper on JNI from Sun now Oracle
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html

And after that it should be understandable but some pseudocode and its not tested would be to move the two gwanapi calls into its own file named gwanapi.java

```
public class gwanapi {
public static native long get_reply(long answer);
public static native void xbuf_cat(long ctx,String str);
}
```

then you compile that file with `javac gwanapi.java` -> output: gwanapi.class
you type javah -jni for the c/c++ header implementation:

```
javah -jni gwanapi
```

the next you should in your hello java class is to call `static{ System.loadLibrary("gwanapi");}`

Pseudo code and NOT tested

```
  public class hello{
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("gwanapi");
    }
    public static int jmain(long env,String args[]){
        gwanapi.xbuf_cat(gwanapi.get_reply(env),"Hello World!");
        return 200;
    }
}
```

and you should be good to go.

But I might have missed a point or two but I think this is the smallest amount of work you should do.

Oh by the way http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface is also some form of source for JNI calls and how it works and lead you to more sites with more information.

Thanks

Comment: I have read that doc (and many many others) and I tried that already. It leads to the same result ("error: gwanapi cannot be resolved"). I also tried to define a 'package' (with the same error). Thank you anyway for the try (I gave you a point for the time spent writing relevant information).